# Equivalent Mongodb idiom for batch queries

Tags: sql, scala, mongodb, batch-file, casbah

What is the most efficient way to query mongo collections in batches? For instance in SQL I'd do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE id > {{floor}} limit 1000;
```

I've found that I can do something as outlined [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bskip%28%29%7D%7D)

but the big warning about skip makes me think I shouldn't use that. (Assume the collection is large enough for it to matter).

My collection doesn't have any indexes besides on the autogenerated _id field. I'm not sure if there is a way to use that and $gt $lt.

If it matters, I'll be using the Casbah driver, in case there is secret sauce built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The literal translation of that SQL query to mongo is

```
db.foo.find({"id": {"$gt": floor}}).limit(1000)
```

This query can be served by an index on the `id` field (or by the default index on `_id` if you use that column instead of one named `id`).

There are no performance issues with `limit()`, but `skip()` for very large values can perform poorly because the server essentially needs to iterate through lots of records before it can begin to return results to you.

Comment: right, I only have the _id default index, and so I don't know the min id to start at. Though, I suppose if I start at 0 and do limit 1000, and then take the last _id and increment it, it could work... right?

Comment: Indeed it appears I can do something like db.foo.find( {_id: { $gt:new ObjectId("000000000000000000000000") } } ).limit(1000) to get me started. Nice.

Comment: For paginagtion, that approach (remembering the last, then starting just after it) is recommended. You can do `db.foo.find({_id: {$gt: {last_object_id}}).sort({_id: 1}).limit(num_per_page)`. Rembmer to use the `sort()` or else you may get quirky results.